# how do I make my script HTML 5 compliant

Tags: html

I am an middle school student learning web programming . I am finding it tough to understand how my browser can understand if my code is HTML or HTML 5 . For example how do I know if my code is HTML or HTML 5 , will any HTML code with the addition of HTML 5 attributes become HTML 5 or is there something to do with the doctype declarations ? I understand this question may be vague or downright stupid but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Here, read this (and if you like, everything else on that site, it's an excellent source for learning): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction

Comment: Formally, HTML5 is a spec, not a version for documents. HTML documents are just HTML, always. Think of it like CSS. There's CSS1, CSS2, CSS3 specs, but your CSS document doesn't say which version of CSS it complies with. Browsers don't care which version of HTML or CSS your document complies with, it treats them all the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to distinguish between a HTML5 document from an older version of HTML, I'd suggest looking at the DOCTYPE, which is perhaps the easiest way. If it looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

it means that it is HTML5. Aditionally, if any [*new* HTML5 elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/elements.html) are present in the document.

[For further reading on the subject](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/).

Comment: Each HTML page should start with a DOCTYPE, but not every DOCTYPE is the same. An xHTML 1.0 Strict DT looks like `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`. HTML5 is the only HTML version that uses the short DT declaration `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes Exactly. Hence, looking at the DOCTYPE it's "fastest" way of determining whether the document will make use of HTML5 elements or not.